# Django1.6, will transaction works for raw SQL?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, mysql-python

Examples from offical document

```python
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])

    cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

if update will affect select, for example

```python
cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = foo + 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
```

Does transaction works for raw SQL,  like this snap code works?

```python
from django.db import connection, transaction

def my_custom_sql(self):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = foo + 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
            cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            return row
    except IntegrityError:
        transaction.rollback()
```

Or the for the first code, begin cursor already start a transaction?

Answer (score 2):

I can see only sanity checks with `self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/db/backends/util.py#L46):

```
def execute(self, sql, params=None):
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
    self.db.set_dirty()
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
        if params is None:
            return self.cursor.execute(sql)
        else:
            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

So the answer is no, cursor doesn't wrap raw SQL in transaction by default.

**Update:**

If you need transactions and [`ATOMIC_REQUESTS = False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-DATABASE-ATOMIC_REQUESTS) you can use `transaction.atomic()` like [decorator or context manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic).

**NB:** `django.db.connection` is there only for backwards comnatibility. You should use `django.db.connections['default']` or even better

```
from django.db import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS

def get_connection(using=None):
    """
    Get a database connection by name, or the default database connection
    if no name is provided.
    """
    if using is None:
        using = DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
    return connections[using]
```

like [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/db/transaction.py#L35)

Comment: so I should add transaction.atomic?

Comment: Oh, sorry. My bad. Yes using `transaction.atomic()` like context manager will do. I've updated my answer